# Facebook client side App authorization in codeigniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authorization

I'm having trouble with facebook javascript client side App authorization. The code below works as expect when the App is not authorized, App authorization popup appears. When the same code runs in codeignigter the authorization dialog fails to appear.

```
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '169550646480230', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
```

Comment: Please post the server side code and more of the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.

Any PHP facebook calls that are run before the Javascript authentication will generate an exception on the server and stop all HTML activity. I guess its called Async for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to two things (I am making assumptions here):

1. CSRF is enabled and blocking the external response from Facebook
2. response from FB is filtered out due to invalid URI characters.

Disable CSRF first, and check if it works, that would be my starting point.

Comment: Looks like it's disabled by default

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;